# How to control font-family font fallback behavior for variation selectors in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

### Background

I am writing an application that uses a wide variety of Japanese character glyphs on Chrome. There are no Japanese fonts that implement all the characters that I want to use in my application.

### What I tried

So I have tried to show Japanese characters by using two or more font files. First I use IPAmj Mincho font ((https://moji.or.jp/mojikiban/font/)), but I use Harano Aji Mincho ((https://github.com/trueroad/HaranoAjiFonts)) for the glyphs not implemented in IPAmj Mincho.

To do this, I have defined two `font-face` as web fonts:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Harano Aji Mincho";
  /* src: url(https://github.com/trueroad/HaranoAjiFonts/raw/master/HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf) format("opentype"); */
  src: url(./HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf) format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "IPAmj Mincho";
  /* src: url(https://github.com/ken1row/IPSJ-techrep-xelatex/raw/master/ipamjm.ttf) format("truetype"); */
  src: url(./ipamjm.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

and add `style="font-family:'IPAmj Mincho','Harano Aji Mincho'"` to HTML tags.

### Problem

If IPAmj Mincho has a glyph for a base character but doesn't have a glyph for a variation selector, when an HTML contains the character with the variation selector, it doesn't fall back to the glyph in Harano Aji Mincho, but shows the glyph for base character in IPAmj Mincho.

For example:

- IPAmjMincho has the glyph for `U+29D4B`([image: , glyph fot U+29D4B]), but doesn't have the glyph for a character in the Adobe-Japan1 character collection with the variation selector `U+E0101` ([image: , glyph for U+29D4B,U+E0101], `U+29D4B, U+E0101`).
- Harano Aji Mincho has glyphs for both `U+29D4B` and `U+29D4B, U+E0101`.

In this situation, if you specify `style="font-family:'IPAmj Mincho','Harano Aji Mincho'"` for a tag, `U+29D4B, U+E0101` is shown with the glyph of `U+29D4B` in IPAmj Mincho, rather than `U+29D4B, U+E0101` in Harano Aji Mincho.

### Question

Is there any way to control the font fallback behavior of the browser to show the glyph `U+29D4B, U+E0101` in Harano Aji Mincho in this situation?

### Edit

You can use the `unicode-range` property for `@font-face`, but there are some problems:

1. You can only specify base characters for `unicode-range`. When you specify variation selectors (for example `U+E0101`) for `unicode-range`, it is just omitted on Chrome version 117.0.5938.149.
2. You have to specify the range of all code points that fonts implement. IPAmj Mincho implements 58,843 Kanji characters ((https://moji.or.jp/wp-content/mojikiban/2019/05/de117ed875e47f87138cc4cd6468de3f.png)). Harano Aji Mincho implements 1,372 glyphs you can specify with variation selectors from `E0101` to `E0109`. So it is impractical to specify all the code point ranges with `unicode-range`.

And also, when you specify `unicode-range: U+29D4B` for Harano Aji Mincho, `U+29D4B` and `U+29D4B, U+E0101` are both displayed with Harano Aji Mincho. I want to display `U+29D4B` in IPAmj Mincho, and `U+29D4B, U+E0101` in Harano Aji Mincho.

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried `unicode-range` property for `@font-face`, but there are some problems. I have added it to the question.

Comment: did you consider the option of having a css class that will explicitely style the dedicated `<span class="harano">` wrapping the intended character? I know it's obvious and not the answer you were looking for.. but so far I can't see a better chance. It could be automated via js looking for text content matching some given characters to be styled with specific `font-family`. I'm not specifically familiar with this problem so that's the max I could suggest unfortunately

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Of course, it works. However it needs a database to solve the relationship between codepoints and font name. The character set used in this application contains 50,000~ characters and is occasionally updated, so this workaround needs extra work for the operation and maintenance.